# How to find the correct version of an assembly to explicitly reference

Tags: f#

I am trying to use the package EikonDataAPI from NuGet in my F# project.

Here is what I did

```
#r @"D:\Dropbox\code\FS foray2\ConsoleApplication1\packages\EikonDataAPI.0.4.3\lib\net45\EikonDataAPI.dll"
//successfully referred

open EikonDataAPI
//no error either

module tester =
    let eikon = Eikon.CreateDataAPI()
    eikon.SetAppKey("abcabcabcabcabc")
    |> ignore
```

when running the code I get an error

```
type 'EikonDataAPI.Eikon' not found in assembly 'EikonDataAPI, Version=2.0.4.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. A possible cause may be a version incompatibility. You may need to explicitly reference the correct version of this assembly to allow all referenced components to use the correct version.
```

I use the net45 (or net40) version of DLL and has no problem (like Deedle.dll) but this one makes me scratch my head.

I also tried to refer (#r) to the EikonDataAPI.dll in lib\netstandard2.0 but got the same problem

Any help would be much appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I finally got it to work:

1. Clone the source code from GitHub
2. Unpack the GitHub zip.  Double click on the .csproj file to open with Visual Studio 2019 (I use the community free version)
3. Right click on the project and Manage Nuget Packages
4. Update all packages in the Update Tab
5. Right click packet.config and change it to package reference
6. Build the solution
7. Copy and paste EikonDataAPI.dll from the bin folder to a folder in my F# project \Packages
8. refer the EikonDataAPI.dll using #r
9. Copy and paste all other .dll in the bin folder to a folder of my choice (say D:\X)
10. Set source_directory to D:\X so that F# Interactive knows where to get the dependencies for the EikonDataAPI.dll

One side note: I am lucky that my F# project uses the latest versions of the common libraries (such as Deedle).  If not, version conflict between the library in F# project and the EikonDataAPI may pose a problem

Lastly many thanks to jirapongse-refinitiv for the API.

Thanks for everyone's help on my other questions on stackoverflow!